# Вывод числа пар одинаковых элементов в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Пожалуйста помогите с программкой. Надо написать программу, которая запрашивает слова пока не введется пустая строка, а затем выводится количество пар. 
Но нельзя использовать функции `max()`, `sort()`, `count()` и в таком духе, а также никакие библиотеки.

```
counter = 0
a = input()
while 1:
    a = input().split()
    if a == '':
        break
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
        if a[i] == a[j]:
            counter += 1

print(counter)
```

вот что у меня получился за код, но это не работает корректно и не могу найти в чем проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя условие выхода из цикла некорректное.
Как вариант можно сделать так:

```
counter = 0
a = []
while 1:
    z = input()
    if z == '':
        break
    else:
        a.append(z)
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(a)):
        if a[i] == a[j]:
            counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: спасибо, сейчас перепишу и попробую

Comment: все работает,  спасибо огромное :)

Comment: @oleksandr_ievlakhov  Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @S.Nick уже отметил :)

Comment: `else` не нужен

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч да но мне нравится как прога выглядит с else